# Mobile Tables - Jquery, so close, stuck on the last part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a script to make my applications tables more mobile friendly.

The tables are all very similar, but very in number of row and columns, since they will be dynamically created, I'll have little control over this, so i've come up with the script below, it almost works but one function is not be passed on to each table, it stops after the first.

I suggest looking at the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4vC3/1/

Here is the piece of the script that is not working correctly:

```
// Create content for new headers in mobile table by copying from original table
var HeaderArray = [];
$("table thead tr th").each(function(){
 var innerArray = [];
    $(this).each(function () {
        innerArray.push($(this).text());
    });
     HeaderArray.push(innerArray); // Put content for new headers in array
});

$("table.mobile_table tbody tr").each(function(index, elem){ // Place content of array where array position and row index are the same
    $(this).find("td").first().text(HeaderArray[index]);
});
```

Again, if you check the fiddle, you will see that the first arry stops copying objects after the first table, i cant get it to run all the way thought.

If anyone could help me with them, i would really, realy appreciate it..... http://jsfiddle.net/e4vC3/1/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are multiple data rows while only 1 header row. So, you will have to use **mod** operator like this(index has been replaced with index % TableSize):

```
    $("table.mobile_table tbody tr").each(function(index, elem){ // Place content of array where array position and row index are the same
    $(this).find("td").first().text(HeaderArray[index % TableSize]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code @ http://jsfiddle.net/souviiik/e4vC3/4/, see if this is helpful. For the first mobile_table I was not able to put the TH values, I hope you can modify my code :)

```
var TableSize = $("#ContactsPhoneTable .tableHedaer").size(); // Get # of columns
var i = 1;
var TableRowCount = $(".no_edit").size(); // Get # of body rows
$(".tableHedaer").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("id", i++); // Give headers incrementing ID
});

for (var CreateTables = 1; CreateTables < TableRowCount; CreateTables++) { // Create new table class="mobile_table" for each row 
    $("table").after("<table class='mobile_table'></table>");
}

for(var i = 0 ; i < TableSize ; i++)
{
    var tableRow = $("<tr/>").appendTo(".mobile_table");
    for(var j = 0 ; j < TableRowCount ; j++)
    {
        var cellValue = $("#ContactsPhoneTable").find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(j).text();
        $("<td/>", {
            text: cellValue
        }).appendTo(tableRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks for giving it a go, but not what I was looking for, it appear you  just dropped the thead section, and possibly the last to columns, and repeated this a few times. In my example, I create a new table that where each row consists of the original table's header, and it's matched content.   Take a look at http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/    see what happens to their tables when you make your browser width mobile size, this is what im trying toacomplish.   Thanks again for you're attempt!

Comment: Are they adding a new table for each row, when the table gets squeezed?

Comment: Yeah, it makes a bunch of mini tables for each row. The first column of each row is the original tables' < th >'s

Answer (score 0):

Updated code is at http://jsfiddle.net/souviiik/b6QZT/2/, see if this is acceptable. The code is as below.

```
var columnCount = $("table thead tr th").not("table.mobile_table thead tr th").size(); // Get # of columns
var rowCount = $("table tbody tr").size(); // Get # of body rows

for (var CreateTables = 0; CreateTables < rowCount; CreateTables++) { // Create new table class="mobile_table" for each row 
    $("<table/>", {
        "class": "mobile_table"
    }).appendTo(".newTableContainer");
}

var tableHedaers = [];

for(var th = 0 ; th < columnCount ; th++)
{
    tableHedaers.push($(".sortable th").eq(th).text());
}

$(".mobile_table").each(function(idx){
    var thisTable = $(this);
    for(var i = 0 ; i < columnCount ; i++)
    {
        var thisTableRow = $("<tr/>").appendTo(thisTable);
        for(var j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
        {
            if(j == 0)
            {
                $("<td/>", {
                    "text": tableHedaers[i],
                    "style": "font-weight: 700"
                }).appendTo(thisTableRow);
            }
            else
            {
                var cellValue = $("#ContactsPhoneTable").find("tr").eq(idx+1).find("td").eq(i).text();

                $("<td/>", {
                    "text": cellValue
                }).appendTo(thisTableRow);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You got the th part correct, but then you hardcoded the other values, they both need to come from the original table....